# Como obtener el listado cuando hay relaciones entre 2 tablas con Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tengo una tabla Curso con el id y el nombre del curso, y otra tabla asistente y esta tiene como clave foranea el idcurso.

Cuando intento hacer esto:

```
db.Asistente.tolist();
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Asistente_95540E48ECC05C557CB4D1C0CBA50CAB4EC196554A880B95659D2966AC32EC6D
```

Estoy usando Entity Framework .Net Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que tener un campo virtual en tu tabla para poder consultarla. tus tablas deberían de verse algo como esto..

```
[Table("Curso")]
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int idCurso{ get; set; }

    public string Descripcion{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Asistente")]
public class Asistente
{
    [Key]
    public int idAsistente{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Curso")]
    public int idCurso{ get; set; }
    public virtual Curso Curso{ get; set; }
}
```

Con esto ya tienes una conexión entra las tablas y puedes hacer las consultas. pero tienes que expresarlo en la consulta como te muestro a continuación:

```
 List<Asistente> Lista = _mydbContext.Asistente.Include(x => x.Curso);
```

Recuerda agregar la libreria using System.Data.Entity;  para que puedas utilizar el Include, ya que te marcara error de lo contrario.